# meteor how to send HTML body in email?

Tags: javascript, email, meteor

I am using `meteor` email package and everything work great besides one problem:

> ```
> Meteor.call('sendEmail',
>   'mail@gmail.com',
>   'postmaster@mailgun.org',
>   'some text' + thisGame.gameNumber,
>   '<div> some HTML body' + some.prop + '</div>'
> );
> ```

Yes,  it works, but what if I have really big mail body I have to write it inline? How can I keep mail body (with some property) in different file and how do I have include it in call function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [ssr](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/ssr) (server-side rendering) package to render HTML server side (including variable substitution obviously) and embed it an email.